# Nhibernate + nuget + syscache

Tags: nhibernate, nuget, syscache

If I install NHibernate and Syscache via nuget, I get a big "Could not load file or assembly" error. Basically Syscache has been built against NH 3.2, but the current version of NH on nuget is 3.3.

Incidentally I had exactly the same issue with NHibernate Validator. It seems someone else had the same issues: [NHibernate 3.3 and SysCache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491876/nhibernate-3-3-and-syscache)

Why is this? I thought nuget was supposed to resolve all these dependency issues. Why is it not possible to get NH + Syscache from a clean install using nuget?

Is there anything to do about it other than download the source of Syscache and build against NH 3.3? I'd really like to be able to manage all my dependencies using nuget only...

Comment: Probably not all related NuGet packages are updated. Have you tried the binding redirect as suggested in one of the answers to the question you mention?

Comment: Since the maintainer for NHibernate.Caches didn't release new bins for 3.3, I didn't update the package either. My suggestion is that you compile it yourself and create the package (you can add a custom source). This way, when it's actually released, you'll be able to just remove the custom source and keep using it.

Comment: Understood. I've not made a nuget package before, and don't really have time at the moment to do that so I'll just build from source for now. This doesn't solve the wider problem of multiple packages that depend on different versions of NHibernate... I thought nuget was intended to solve this?

Comment: @Diego if you add your comment as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the maintainer for NHibernate.Caches didn't release new bins for 3.3, I didn't update the package either.

My suggestion is that you compile it yourself and create the package (you can add a custom source). This way, when it's actually released, you'll be able to just remove the custom source and keep using it.